# Jacoco + JUnit 5.0 DynamicTest not working

Tags: spring-boot, jacoco, junit5, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate a code coverage report using Jacoco with JUnit 5 and Spring Boot. And I"m trying to use the DynamicTest feature of JUnit 5. It runs successfully but the Dynamic Tests are not covered in the test coverage report generated by jacoco. Is JUnit 5 Dynamic Test not covered by Jacoco at the moment?

Here is the code:

```
    @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
    @SelectPackages("com.troll.jpt.abc.model")
    @SelectClasses({Status.class})
    public class DynamicModelTester {

    private Status status;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        status = new Status();
    }

    @TestFactory
    public Stream<DynamicTest> checkDynamicTestsFromStream() {

        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("abc");
        List<String> output = Arrays.asList("abc");

        status.setCode(input.get(0));

        return input.stream().map(str ->  DynamicTest.dynamicTest("status test", () -> {
            assertEquals(output.get(0), status.getCode());
        }));
    }
}
```

The jacoco plugin I'm using is as :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->

                    <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                    <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                    <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It runs successfully but the Dynamic Tests are not covered in the test coverage report generated by jacoco.

`jacoco-maven-plugin:report` doesn't display coverage in tests, it displays coverage of a target of a test - in your case target seems to be class `Status`, whose definition is completely absent.

---

Generic answer on questions like "does JaCoCo support JUnit 5 Dynamic Test?" is: **JaCoCo records fact that code was executed independently from the way how it was executed** - via JUnit 4 or JUnit 5, or even manually or whatever the other way of execution.

And generic answer on questions like "why some code is not marked as covered?" is: **make sure that code is actually executed**, in case of automatic tests this means - **make sure that these tests are actually executed**.

But let's give a try with JUnit 5 Dynamic Test. In absence of `src/main/java/Status.java` I'll assume that it is something like

```
public class Status {

  private String code;

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

}
```

No idea why you need `systemPropertyVariables`, snapshot version of `jacoco-maven-plugin`, multiple executions of `report` and redundant specification of `dataFile` with its default value, so will also assume that complete `pom.xml` after slight cleanup looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

After placing

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestFactory;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("com.troll.jpt.abc.model")
@SelectClasses({Status.class})
public class DynamicModelTester {

  private Status status;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    status = new Status();
  }

  @TestFactory
  public Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromStream() {
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList("abc");
    List<String> output = Arrays.asList("abc");

    status.setCode(input.get(0));

    return input.stream().map(str ->  DynamicTest.dynamicTest("status test", () -> {
      assertEquals(output.get(0), status.getCode());
    }));
  }

}
```

into `src/test/java/DynamicModelTester.java` and execution of `mvn clean verify`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ example ---
[INFO] Building jar: /private/tmp/jacoco/target/example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.1:report (default) @ example ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
```

Last line is quite suspicious as well as absence of number of tests executed by `maven-surefire-plugin` together with absence of `target/surefire-reports/`.

Let's rename `DynamicModelTester` into `DynamicModelTest` and execute `mvn clean verify` again:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running DynamicModelTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.023 s - in DynamicModelTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ example ---
[INFO] Building jar: /private/tmp/jacoco/target/example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.1:report (default) @ example ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /private/tmp/jacoco/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'example' with 1 classes
```

Compared to previous attempt test was executed this time. And coverage report `target/jacoco-ut/default/Status.html` looks like:

[image: coverage report]

I believe that the reason of the fact that test is not executed lies in a [default value of `includes` of `maven-surefire-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) :

> A list of  elements specifying the tests (by pattern) that
> should be included in testing. When not specified and when the test
> parameter is not specified, the default includes will be
>
> ```
> <includes>
>     <include>**/Test*.java</include>
>     <include>**/*Test.java</include>
>     <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
>     <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
> </includes>
> ```

`DynamicModelTester.java` doesn't match any of these patters, while `DynamicModelTest.java` matches second, but I'll leave verification of this as a little exercise.